# Aurelia Event Aggregator not working properly.

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I want just to publish and subscribe on a simple event with the Aurelia Event aggregator. It do not even publish on first load i need to go several times to the class2 and them after a while it starts publishing. I dont know what is the problem here. Thank you all for help

```
import { autoinject } from "aurelia-framework";
import { Router } from "aurelia-router";
import { EventAggregator } from "aurelia-event-aggregator";
import { TestEvent } from 'shared/TestEvent';

@autoinject
export class Class1{
  constructor(private router: Router, private ea: EventAggregator){
    this.ea = ea;
  }

  try(){
    this.ea.publish(new TestEvent);
  }
}

import { autoinject, observable } from "aurelia-framework";
import { Router } from "aurelia-router";
import { EventAggregator } from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';
import { TestEvent } from 'shared/TestEvent';

@autoinject
export class Class2{
  subscription: any;
  constructor(private router: Router, private ea: EventAggregator) {
  }

  attached() {
    this.subscription = this.ea.subscribe(TestEvent, ()=>{
      console.log("message")
    })
  }
  detached(){
    this.subscription.dispose();
  }

TestEvent.cs 
export class TestEvent{}
```

Comment: Where do you call the `try` function?

Comment: i have   <button click.delegate="try()">try</button>
in the html of class1, try is checked and is called that's for sure

Comment: `this.ea = ea; ` is missing in Class2 constructor

Comment: That's not necessary as they are using `@autoinject` in TypeScript.

Comment: Do you have the necessary parenthesis that are missing in the call to `new TestEvent()` in `Class1` or is that just an error made while writing up the question?

Comment: It was not working because i was going this way. 
I had 3 steps, The first step is info from class 1, the second step is info from class 2 and the third step is info from both.
So lets say am on the first step and i click next then i wanted to publish the event and to subscribe it on the third step. But its not possible because i want to subscribe on the third step but am going on the second step and that way event is not working. I need to pass the info from step 1 to step 2 then from step 2 to step 3. I dont know if this was really the issue but i guess so, that solved it !

Comment: please provide a repro